# How to make a counter in VBA that won't count when the same button is clicked

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

As part of my school project, I am making multiple choice program for my teacher as my client using VBA in MS access. there is a form which will have many records for each question. Using the gotonextrecord button I am able to select the next question. But I have used a counter to check if the right answer is selected on each record. now when the user finishes one question and if he clicks the option button twice for the same question, then the counter will be counting. How do I stop the counter, counting when the user clicks the button on the same record twice or for an infinite number of time.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAXSE.png)

Comment: You must post your code, also the the tag access is not right for ms access questions.

Comment: Please post the code as text.

Comment: disable the button?

Comment: no the counter shouldn't work when the user clicks the same button twice. I am not disabling the button because I need to provide the user an option to come back to the question to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the name of the button as a module-level variable (as you are doing with the counter variable):

```
Dim NameOfButtonToCheck = "Option110"
```

You'll need a shared handler for all possible buttons:

```
Private Sub SharedHandler(buttonName As String)
    If buttonName = NameOfButtonToCheck Then Exit Sub
    ...
End Sub
```

Each button's handler should call the shared handler, passing in the name (which uniquely identifies the control):

```
Private Sub Option110_Click()
    SharedHandler "Option110"
End Sub
```

---

A better approach would be to store the student's entry in a record:

```
Entries
----------
StudentID
TestID
ChoiceID
```

When the user presses the button, if no such record exists for the student/test, create it. Otherwise, modify the existing record.

The calculation of how many answers the user got right should be a count of these records; and thus independent of the number of times the user pressed the button.